# Calibrating HW 1f model params to a term structure market data

Tags: programming, quantlib, swaption

I am using Quantlib to calibrate the HW model params to the market swaption price. The attached chart shows the performance of the calibration.

Am I correct in saying, this is expected for the 1f HW model i.e. it will struggle to fit to such an observed skew [image]